# Find "old" rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

Consider a table like this:

| txn_id     |   account_id

I'd like to do a single query that will get me all txn_ids for all transactions where the transaction is not the most recent (highest txn_id) for the account_id .

The database is MySQL 5.1, so that might imply some limitations around sub-selects.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I think that MySQL is too stupid to do any of your suggestions at sufficient performance, so I'll have to do some ugly workaround, but I appreciate the effort to help. When I am on another project with a better database, I'll use these suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right

```
SELECT txn_id
  FROM table
 WHERE txn_id <> (SELECT MAX(txn_id) FROM table WHERE account_id = 123456)
   AND account_id = 123456
```

Comment: No.  At minimum, you would need to qualify the sub-select with 'WHERE account_id = 123456'.  See the answer by artemb which does this.

Comment: D'oh.. absolutely. I fixed my answer

Answer (score 2):

Given the requirement:

> I'd like to do a single query that will get me all txn_ids for all transactions where the transaction is not the most recent (highest txn_id) for the account_id.

it seems that answers which give you transaction IDs for a single account at a time are missing the point of the query.

To get the list of transaction IDs that must be retained (or ignored) we can write:

```
SELECT MAX(txn_id) AS max_txn_id, account_id
  FROM UnnamedTable
 GROUP BY account_id;
```

Now we need to get the list of transaction IDs not found in that list.  That isn't wholly straight-forward:

```
SELECT txn_id, account_id
  FROM UnnamedTable
 WHERE txn_id NOT IN
             (SELECT max_txn_id
                FROM (SELECT MAX(txn_id) AS max_txn_id, account_id
                        FROM UnnamedTable
                       GROUP BY account_id
                     )
             )
```

Anyway, that works OK with IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.50 and the table and data below:

```
create table unnamedtable(txn_id integer not null, account_id integer not null);
insert into unnamedtable values(1, 12);
insert into unnamedtable values(2, 12);
insert into unnamedtable values(3, 12);
insert into unnamedtable values(4, 13);
```

yielding the results:

```
1    12
2    12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select txn_id, account_id
order by txn_id desc
limit 1,18446744073709551615;
```

Comment: +1. The best choice if you have no order preferences. If you do, gotta go with sub-selection

Comment: Can you explain how this works - because I don't see why it works at all.

Comment: It sorts the records on txn_id in reverse order meaning the highest txn_id will go to the top. Then it returns all the records beginning from the second one, effectively skipping the record with the highest txn_id

Comment: @artemb: okay - thanks for the explanation.  I'm not clear how the proposed SQL answers the question, but at least the query is clearer.  (I see from the manuals that LIMIT starts offsets at zero, rather than using 1 as most of the rest of SQL does; that was part of my confusion.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select txn_id from table 
where account_id = 123 and 
txn_id < (select max(txn_id) from table where account_id = 123)
```

Comment: That's fine for one account at a time.  I think the question is seeking to execute the equivalent of that statement for each account_id value.